# Are the 4th and 5th extensions to the 3 Laws of Robotics validated by Asimov?

Tags: robots, isaac-asimov, laws-of-robotics

Wikipedia cites extensions **by other authors** to the canonical "Three laws" as follows

> There are two Fourth Laws written by authors other than Asimov. The
>   1974 Lyuben Dilov novel Icarus's Way (a.k.a. The Trip of Icarus)
>   introduced a Fourth Law of robotics:
>
> ```
> A robot must establish its identity as a robot in all cases.
> ```
>
> Dilov gives reasons for the fourth safeguard in this way: "The last
>   Law has put an end to the expensive aberrations of designers to give
>   psychorobots as humanlike a form as possible. And to the resulting
>   misunderstandings..."[29]
>
> For the 1986 tribute anthology Foundation's Friends Harry Harrison
>   wrote a story entitled, "The Fourth Law of Robotics". This Fourth Law
>   states:
>
> ```
> A robot must reproduce. As long as such reproduction does not
> interfere with the First or Second or Third Law.
> ```
>
> In the book a robot rights activist, in an attempt to liberate robots,
>   builds several equipped with this Fourth Law. The robots accomplish
>   the task laid out in this version of the Fourth Law by building new
>   robots who view their creator robots as parental figures.[30]
>
> A fifth law was introduced by Nikola Kesarovski in his short story
>   "The Fifth Law of Robotics". This fifth law says:
>
> ```
> A robot must know it is a robot.
> ```

My interest is primarily focused on the first of the 4th laws (4a if you prefer) and the 5th law.

Was Asimov made aware of these extensions during his lifetime and is there any documented evidence to support any opinion he had on them?

Comment: You neglect the Zeroth law, which Asimov supplied. A robot may not harm humanity, or, by inaction, allow humanity to come to harm

Comment: Asimov supplied that rule himself so it is already valid

Comment: I am not sure how @geoffc comment is in scope of this question. The first three rules are accepted, this is a question about the 4th and 5th.

Comment: @Pyrodante Mostly because the issue starts with laws other than the first three, and there is an other than the first three not mentioned.

Comment: @geoffc I neglected nothing. This question relates directly to "4th and 5th" extensions of what is commonly referred to as "the three laws" (regardless of whether one includes zeroeth or not).

Comment: I could imagine such a fourth law only in context of the Caliban universe.

Comment: It seems to me that since the third law (presumably) overrules any further ones, any further ones are equivalent to "the last orders we were given". They make sense only in the context of a robot culture lacking human contact.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Asimov repeatedly wrote in his essays and autobiography that his Three Laws of Robotics became a basic concept of science fiction, and were used by other authors. However, he makes it clear that no other author ever *quoted* the Three Laws, only ever *assumed* them implicitly - which is how Asimov preferred it. Other authors could assume that robots would behave according to Asimov's Three Laws of Robotics, but only Asimov could quote them.

> Now it is understood that science fiction writers generally have created a pool of ideas that form a common stock into which all writers can dip. For that reason, I have never objected to other writers who have used robots that obey the Three Laws. [...] However, I have firmly resisted the actual quotation of the Three Laws by any other writer. Take the Laws for granted, is my attitude in this matter, but don't recite them. The concepts are everyone's but the words are mine.

**'My Robots', an essay in the collection *Robot Visions***

However, he never mentions any additional laws (except his own Zeroth Law). Given his attitude that he preferred for other authors not to quote his Three Laws, but only assume them, I think he would NOT give his official approval to any additions to his Laws.

Comment: any documented evidence to support this view

Comment: "Now it is understood that science fiction writers generally have created a pool of ideas that form a common stock into which all writers can dip. For that reason, I have never objected to other writers who have used robots that obey the Three Laws. [...]

However, I have firmly resisted the actual quotation of the Three Laws by any other writer. Take the Laws for granted, is my attitude in this matter, but don't recite them. The concepts are everyone's but the words are mine."


'My Robots', an essay in the collection 'Robot Visions'.

Other writers could *assume* the Laws, not *quote* them.

Comment: I just read the Robot City series. A series supported by Azimov. In the foreword of the first novel "Odyssey" he mentions (and I quote): "...it is just as well if I relax my rules and allow others to make use of them (the Laws) and reinvigorate them."

Comment: @VincentVancalbergh: be careful, Asimov didn't like when people spelt his name wrong.  By Robot City series, do you mean the *Caliban* trilogy by Roger MacBride Allen?

Comment: @b_jonas, No I mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov's_Robot_City. And I deeply regret misspelling his name. Unfortunately, I can't edit the comment anymore :(

Comment: Oh, *that* Robot City.  I was wondering because I think the *Caliban* trilogy probably quotes the three laws somewhere.